# Angular router doesn't navigate for the first time from component to component

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to redirect from signup component to challenge component after signup. If the local storage not set into the challenge component it will redirect to the signup component. My problem is to it will not navigate from signup to challenge component for the first time signup.

challange.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('userId') != null) {
     ......
    }
    else{
      this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
    }

  }
```

signup.component.ts

```
signupNew() {
    this.signupService.doSignup(this.parameter);
    this.router.navigate(['/challange']);
}
```

signup.service.ts

```
doSignup(signParam : SignupParam) {
    this.signupCollection.add(signParam).then(ref => {
      localStorage.setItem('userId', ref.id);
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('userId'))
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Check your Internet connection...');
    })
  }
```

route.ts

```
export const appRoutes : Routes = [
    { path : 'signup', component : SignupComponent },
    { path : 'challange', component: ChallangeComponent},
    { path : 'feed', component: NewsFeedComponent},
    { path : 'items-initial', component: InitialItemComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch : 'full'}
];
```

Comment: can you show us your rote config?

Comment: And are you getting any error? Did you debug your code to see that the router.navigate code is being called?

Comment: When i click challenge menu it will directly redirect to the signup. After signup it will not redirect. Then i do again signup it will redirect. So i face two signup. No error occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is here:

```
this.signupService.doSignup(this.parameter);
this.router.navigate(['/challange']);
```

`doSignup` is asynchronous and you are not synchronizing it, so the router is navigating to `/challange` *before* `userId` is set in local storage which leads to another redirect the first time. However, at that point, the `userId` would be in localStorage. Synchronize these calls:

```
async doSignup(signParam : SignupParam) {
  // error handling omitted
  const ref = await this.signupCollection.add(signParam);
  localStorage.setItem('userId', ref.id);
}

async signupNew() {
  await this.signupService.doSignup(this.parameter);
  this.router.navigate(['/challange']);
}
```

Comment: one more thing can i redirect from service files?

Comment: @Rijo you could redirect from your service because `Router` can be injected into the service, but I personally would not do UI-related things like routing in a service because then the routing functionality is tightly coupled to the signup functionality and you lose flexibility if you want to add a user without this specific routing. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: I have trouble its not working. Service file what i re-write "async doSignup(signParam : SignupParam) {
    await this.signupCollection.add(signParam).then(ref => {
      localStorage.setItem('userId', ref.id);
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('userId'))
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Check your Internet connection...');
    })
  } "   **signup.componnet.ts** async signupNew() {
   if(this.parameter.firstName != '' ) {
    await this.signupService.doSignup(this.parameter);
    this.parameter.firstName = ''; this.router.navigate(['/challange']);}} Its not navigating

Comment: are you sure it's reaching the `this.router.navigate` line? Btw it says _challange_ rather than _challenge_, so not sure if that's a typo. I just transcribed that from your question